# ArgoCD ignore specific annotation escaping slashes and times

Tags: jsonpath, argocd

Using [this feature](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/diffing/), I need to ignore the annoation ( `openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups` ) from the Sync of resources of type `Namespace`.
I tried the following:

1- using `[]`

```yaml
  - kind: Namespace
    jsonPointers:
      - '/metadata/annotations["openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups"]'
```

2- escape any `.` or `/` by `\`

```yaml
  - kind: Namespace
    jsonPointers:
      - /metadata/annotations/openshift\.io\/sa\.scc\.supplemental-groups
```

3- wildcard

```yaml
  - kind: Namespace
    jsonPointers:
      - /metadata/annotations/openshift*
```

Nothing work ! any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Argocd's ignoreDifference uses the [Json Pointer syntax](https://jsonpatch.com/#json-pointer).

You need to replace `/` with `~1` and `~` with `~0`.

In your example:

```
- kind: Namespace
  jsonPointers:
    - '/metadata/annotations/openshift.io~1sa.scc.supplemental-groups'
```

`.` do not need to be escaped.